# What is the best way to pass data from one app to another app

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

What is the best way to pass data from one app to another app.

I have a two extJS app lets called appA and appB.

In my appA I am using some of the views of appB. Therefore I need to pass some data to be passed.

what is the correct way to pass the data.

Currently I am using

```
var myOb= {"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2"}

    sessionStorage.setItem('obJectData', muObj);
```

After use I am removing this like

sessionStorage.removeItem("obJectData");

Can anyone help me how and where to store the data in correct way.

I also have a though to be global vaiable.

Comment: Do the apps need to update in realtime to changes in each other?  Are they run in the same tab, or different tabs?

Comment: Actually when i implement some complex use cases then i am passing the data on realtime changes. They are running in same tab.

Comment: Do apps have different domain ? and does data change on some event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have this across several different microapps all loaded on the same page, you might consider a combo approach of:

1. A singleton that holds the current shared state items
2. An events bus that can be used for [pubsub (publish-subscribe)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) so that components/apps can subscribe to events and get updates when changes occur.

A rudimentary example could be seen here:

```js
const appState = {
  count: 0,
};

const eventBus = {
  // just using the built-in DOM handlers, but you could create a custom one
  subscribe: (eventName, handler) => document.addEventListener(eventName, handler),
  publish: (eventName, payload) => document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(eventName, payload)),
};

const incrementCount = () => {
  appState.count = appState.count + 1;
  eventBus.publish('newCount', { detail: { count: appState.count } });
}

const addCountDisplay = () => {
  const newDisplay = document.createElement('div');
  newDisplay.classList.add('countDisplay');
  newDisplay.textContent = appState.count;
  document.body.append(newDisplay);
}

// updateAllCountDisplays
eventBus.subscribe('newCount', (e) => {
  const newCount = e.detail.count;
  const displays = document.querySelectorAll('.countDisplay');
  ([...displays]).forEach((display) => display.textContent = newCount.toString());
});
```

```html
<button onclick="incrementCount()">increment count</button>
<button onclick="addCountDisplay()">add count display</button>
```

In this example, you can see that:

1. Anytime you create a new count display, it is able to fetch the current count from the singleton `appState`
2. Anytime you update the count, a custom event is triggered that is able to be subscribed to to update the UI in reaction to the change in state

This could obviously be improved in many ways, but it serves as an example of how you can combine a globally available singleton in memory serving as a state cache with custom events to give all your components access to the current state as well as a way to subscribe and react to changes in state.  This is not the only pattern you could use; it's just one option to consider.

Comment: This looks like a perfect solution. let me works on this and will update you. thank you.

Comment: As you are asking for ExtJS I would suggest to use the ExtJS bus.
MyWorkspace = {}; MyWorkspace.Bus = new Ext.util.Observable(); MyWorkspace.Bus.on('myevent', fn); MyWorkspace.Bus.fireEvent('myevent', ...args)

Comment: @David -see the above comment from Dinkheller; it appears that ExtJS may expose its own global bus-- if so, that would probably be the preferred approach.

Comment: @Dinkheller - thanks for sharing this information-- how different is it? It may be worth creating a separate answer if there is a ExtJS idiomatic approach you know that differs significantly from my solution...

Comment: @Dinkheller Thanks for your comment. When i was going through the doc of ExtJS.Bus I got this statment "NOTE: This is a private utility class for internal use by the framework. Don't rely on its existence." So I am little confuse on its implementation.

Comment: @AlexanderNied This approach is also working fine for me. Using singleton and the add all the required stuff in the evets

Comment: @David Not sure where you get that from. I am talking about the usage of: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.util.Observable.html   || This one will create the Bus. With a separate Namespace you are good to use it between different apps.

Comment: @Dinkheller Ya this is for modern toolkit. I am using classic hwere i got that, Thanks for your effort DInkheller

Comment: @David here is the link to classic, which is the same and not a private utility ;) : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.util.Observable.html